# C++ private constructor (with argument) does not allow instantiation

Tags: c++, constructor, private, friend

I have a problem in my private constructor as below:

Lane.hpp:

```
namespace sim_mob
{
class B
{

    friend class A;

private:
    B(int){}

};
}
```

xmll.hpp:

```
#include"Lane.hpp"
namespace geo
{
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        sim_mob::B b(2);
     }
};
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include"xmll.hpp"



int main()
{
    geo::A a;
    return 0;
}
```

command:
$ g++ main.cpp

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
Lane.hpp: In constructor ‘geo::A::A()’:
Lane.hpp:10:5: error: ‘sim_mob::B::B(int)’ is private
xmll.hpp:9:23: error: within this context
```

The point is if I didn't have any arguments in the constructor, I wouldn't receive this error. May I Know why i am getting this and how to solve it?
many Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In class `sim_mob::B` you befriend a class `sim_mob:A` but you hope that this friendship extends to `geo::A` which it, obviously, does not. To solve this you'd need a declaration of `geo::A` before making it a friend:

```
namespace geo { class A; }
namespace sim_mob
{
    class B
    {
        friend class geo::A;
    private:
        B(int){}
    };
}
```

The fact that it "works" with the default constructor is, I guess, that you rather declared a function than instantiate an object:

```
sim_mob::B b();
```

is a function declaration. If you leave off the parenthesis you should get an error about the default constructor not existing or, if you actually declare it, not being accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Forward declare:

```
namespace geo{
class A;
}
```

In class B:

```
friend class geo::A;
```

Answer (score 0):

`friend class A;` friends class `A` in the current namespace, i.e. `sim_mob::A`, not `geo::A`. You need to declare the class, and then use fully qualified name:

```
namespace bar { struct bar; }
namespace foo {
    struct foo {
    private:
        friend struct bar::bar;
        explicit foo(int) {}
    };
}

namespace bar {
    struct bar {
        bar() { foo::foo x(42); }
    };
}
```